# What's the expression used by Americans when referring to a "postcode" outside of the US?

Tags: american-english

I always assumed "zip code" was the American way of referring to a postal code regardless of where the address may be. However, a friend is telling me that the use of "zip code" to refer to addresses outside the US is incorrect. I find this very curious. Why would Americans use one word for addresses located in the US and a different one for the ones abroad.

Comment: If you use *zip code* instead of *postal code* for addresses outside the U.S., you will be technically wrong, but everybody will understand what you mean.

Comment: There is no established term in the US (other than the obscure terms the Postal Service buries in its documents), since mailing outside the US is so rare.  (And, in fact, mailing at all is becoming rarer and rarer.)

Comment: Why use different words? I can imagine a Parisien would use _quartier_ when referring to a city area in, say, London, rather than _arrondissement_ as they call it in Paris. As GEdgar says, a ZIP code is a postal code, but not every postal code is a ZIP code.

Comment: ZIP Codes are specific to the US.  _[ZIP Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code) are a system of postal codes used by the United States Postal Service since 1963. The term ZIP, an acronym for Zone Improvement Plan, was chosen to suggest that the mail travels more efficiently, and therefore more quickly (zipping along), when senders use the code in the postal address._

Comment: So, all ZIP Codes are postal codes but not all postal codes are ZIP Codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I would say "postal code" for anywhere, including here in the US, but "zip code" only for the US.  Why would we do it?  Because "zip code" is a particular kind of postal code.

Comment: Also, I would say "postal code" but not "postcode".  My dictionary suggests "postcode" is common in British English.

Comment: Isn't *postcode* what folks do on [codereview.se]? :-)